# On click Delete Img button it deletes the image and goes to homepage but after doing this two times it works fine

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

This is an cordova android app. Whenever i click on the delete img button it deletes the img and goes to home page but after doing two times it deletes img stays on same page which is fine.

I don't want it go to homepage. Please help.

//Html page

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="server-div" style="display:none;">
        Server URL :<input type="text" name="server_1" id="server_1" 
        value="http://www.indiafastener.com/webservices/listing/upload.php" />
    </div>
    <div id="gallery_images_list"></div>
    <br>
    <div><button style="color: black" id="remImg" onclick="delImg()" 
         hidden>Delete Image</button>
    </div>
    <br><img id="loader_icon" src="images/loader.gif" style="display:none;" />
    <br>
    <div id="picture_msg_1" style="color:green;font-size:11px;"> </div>
    <br>
    <div id="image-upload" onClick="uploadImageGallery()">
        <img id="pimage_1" src="images/file-upload-1.png" width="64px" 
        height="64px" />
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="server_image_url_1" id="server_image_url_1">

</div>
```

//Code

```
//Upload image
function uploadImageGallery() {

        var imgage = document.getElementById('pimage_1');
        //$("#add_company_category").val("Loading gallery...");
        //$("#add_company_category").html("Loading gallery...");
        $("#loader_icon").css('display', 'block');
        document.getElementById('picture_msg_1').innerHTML = "";
        // Get URI of picture to upload
        navigator.camera.getPicture(
            function(uri) {
                try {

                    // Pick image from div
                    var img = document.getElementById('pimage_1');
                    //   var img_11 = document.getElementById('pimage_11');
                    img.style.visibility = "visible";
                    img.style.display = "block";
                    var imageURI = uri;
                    if (!imageURI || (img.style.display == "none")) {
                        document.getElementById('picture_msg_1').innerHTML = "Tap on picture to select image from gallery.";
                        return;
                    }
                    // Verify server has been entered
                    server = document.getElementById('server_1').value;
                    //  server = http +'/webservices/listing/upload.php';
                    server = http + '/gallery-upload.php?post_id=' + localStorage.post_id_1;
                    console.log("Server " + server);
                    //        alert("Server "+server);
                    if (server) {
                        // Specify transfer options
                        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                        options.fileKey = "file";
                        options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                        options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
                        options.chunkedMode = false;

                        // Transfer picture to server
                        var ft = new FileTransfer();
                        ft.upload(imageURI, server, function(r) {
                                document.getElementById('picture_msg_1').innerHTML = "Upload successful: " + r.bytesSent + " bytes uploaded.";
                                //  img.src = uri;
                                //  img.width = 50;
                                //  img.height = 50;
                                $("#gallery_images_list").append('<img src="' + uri + '" style="width:50px;" id="im">');
                                // shows delete img button
                                document.getElementById('remImg').removeAttribute('hidden');
                                $("#server_image_url_1").val(r.response.toString());
                                //$("#add_company_category").val("Submit & Finish");
                                //$("#add_company_category").html("Submit & Finish");
                                $("#loader_icon").css('display', 'none');

                            },
                            function(error) {
                                document.getElementById('picture_msg_1').innerHTML = "Upload failed: Code = " + error.code;
                            }, options);
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById('picture_msg_1').innerHTML = "Server Not Found";
                    }
                } catch (exce) {
                    navigator.notification.alert(exce);
                }
            },
            function(e) {
                console.log("Error getting picture: " + e);
                document.getElementById('picture_msg_1').innerHTML = "No Image Found";
            }, {
                quality: 50,
                destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
            }
        );
    }

    // Delete image
    function delImg() {
        $(function() {
            document.getElementById('im').remove();
            document.getElementById('picture_msg_1').innerHTML = "Image Removed";

            delBtn();
        });
    };

// Hide Delete Button

    function delBtn() {
        var x = document.getElementById('gallery_images_list').childElementCount;
        if (x < 1) {
            document.getElementById('remImg').setAttribute('hidden');
            document.getElementById('picture_msg_1').innerHTML = "";
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 2:**

Try changing this

```
function delBtn() {
    var x = document.getElementById('gallery_images_list').childElementCount;
    if (x < 1) {
        document.getElementById('remImg').setAttribute('hidden');
        document.getElementById('picture_msg_1').innerHTML = "";
    }

};
```

to this

```
function delBtn() {
    var x = document.getElementById('gallery_images_list').childElementCount;
    if (x < 1) {
        $('#remImg').attr('hidden', true);
        $('#picture_msg_1').html("");
    }

};
```

**Edit:**

Try changing this code:

```
function delImg() {
    $(function() {
        document.getElementById('im').remove();
        document.getElementById('picture_msg_1').innerHTML = "Image Removed";

        delBtn();
    });
};
```

To this.

```
function delImg() {
        $('#im').remove();
        $('#picture_msg_1').html("Image Removed");

        delBtn();
};
```

I think you are using the remove() method wrong. You need to know the parent and remove children from that like this.

```
var child = document.getElementById("p1");

child.parentNode.removeChild(child);
```

This example was taken from here.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp

You could also use jQuery.

```
$('#id').remove()
```

Comment: Thanks dear, tried your method but the same problem continues. For first two time it goes to home page and in third time it stays on same page. MY problem why it is going to homepage for first two time.

Comment: I have added another suggestion to my answer.

Comment: Don't suppose you tried my edit above? Curious to know if it worked.

Comment: I think when i click on delete img button it reloads the page for first two times.

Comment: Yes i tried your code but still same problem continues

Comment: Added another edit. Just to try see if you need to pass true on the hidden attribute.